# How to quickly / easily install all required packages from DESCRIPTION file?

Tags: r

R packages, repos, other projects (e.g. bookdown) often have a file called `DESCRIPTION` which lists packages required for the project.

Is there a quick and easy way to install the required packages?

Answer (score 2):

If you want minimal dependencies, then you can write a wrapper based on `read.dcf`.  Mine takes a `DESCRIPTION` file and returns a character vector listing the (optionally reverse, optionally recursive) dependencies of the described package.  You would install (as usual) by passing the result or a subset to `install.packages` ...

```r
function(file, db = NULL, ...) {
    dsc <- read.dcf(file)[1L, ] # assuming ASCII; see tools:::.read_description
    pkg <- dsc["Package"]
    if (is.null(db))
        db <- utils::available.packages()
    db <- rbind(db[db[, "Package"] != pkg, , drop = FALSE], 
                dsc[colnames(db)])
    tools::package_dependencies(pkg, db, ...)[[1L]]
}
```

I've just tested a bit ... it seems to do what I want ...

```r
> description_dependencies <- function(file, db = NULL, ...) {
+     dsc <- read.dcf(file)[1L, ] # assuming ASCII; see tools:::.read_description
+     pkg <- dsc["Package"]
+     if (is.null(db))
+         db <- utils::available.packages()
+     db <- rbind(db[db[, "Package"] != pkg, , drop = FALSE],
+                 dsc[colnames(db)])
+     tools::package_dependencies(pkg, db, ...)[[1L]]
+ }
> tf <- tempfile()
> writeLines(con = tf,
+            c("Package: zzz",
+              "Version: 0.0.1",
+              "Depends: R (>= 3.5.0), methods",
+              "LinkingTo: Matrix (>= 1.6-1)",
+              "Imports:\n\tstats,\n\ttools,\n\tutils",
+              "Suggests: lattice, nlme",
+              "Enhances: MatrixModels"))
> db <- available.packages() # expensive, so reuse
> description_dependencies(tf, db, which = "all")
[1] "methods"      "stats"        "tools"        "utils"        "Matrix"      
[6] "lattice"      "nlme"         "MatrixModels"
> description_dependencies(tf, db, which = "most")
[1] "methods" "stats"   "tools"   "utils"   "Matrix"  "lattice" "nlme"   
> description_dependencies(tf, db, which = "strong")
[1] "methods" "stats"   "tools"   "utils"   "Matrix" 
> description_dependencies(tf, db, which = c("Suggests", "Enhances"))
[1] "lattice"      "nlme"         "MatrixModels"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to install all packages listed in the DESCRIPTION file:

```r
remotes::install_deps(upgrade = "always")
```

The `upgrade = "always"` argument automatically responds `1` (yes, install all) to prompts asking whether the also update dependencies of those packages.

Comment: I came across this incredibly useful function today, so sharing here. I won't accept this answer in case there are other/better ways (please share if there are).

Comment: I have a wrapper of that function in `littler` script `installDeps.r`.  Works great in CI or on containers when you have source directory with a `DESCRIPTION`.  Works especially well with [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) and all dependencies come within seconds as binaries with their dependencies.